# How to emulate file directory of a URL using Php -S?

Tags: php, xml, url

My task is like:

Kannel exposes a status xml.
Services before interacting the kannel usually query its status before engaging with it.
The library should query the xml, parse it's content and create a structure to access it's values by name.
The library construction options should include kannel host, port and password.

> The query uri is as : http://{host}:{port}/status.xml?password={password}

What can I do to emulate the file directory(status.xml) of a URL as shown above? (my manager told me to use php -s)

```
public function __construct($host, $port, $password=""){
$this->$host= $host;
$this->$port= $port;
$this->$password= $password;
$this->$url =  $host . $port . $password ;

$this->$response_xml_data = file_get_contents($url);
$this->$data = simplexml_load_string($response_xml_data);
```

}

My constructur parameters like :

```
$XmlClass = new XmlReaderClass('localhost', '8000');
```

But I take the warning :

> Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty

Comment: You can change http://  to file:// so you put file local like file://c:\temp\status.xml

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco my manager told me not to use any framework and look up for php -s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"-s" flag in the PHP terminal helps to run a built-in webserver.(PHP [Built-in web server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php))

Think like you have a *status.xml* in your *public_html* folder. You can run it in a directory like the following code through terminal:

```
cd ~/public_html
php -S localhost:8000
```

When you request for *localhost:8000/status.xml*, you get *status.xml content* through to your client.

Also, you can use a specified file as a default page through the built-in webserver.

```
cd ~/public_html
php -S localhost:8000 status.xml
```

When you request for *localhost:8000*, you get *status.xml content* through to your client.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But still, I need to know how to give Url parameters to constructor method to run the xml page in the local server? (and what should parameters be?)